# Set li wrap padding

Tags: css

I have tried but can not make li tag wrap completely a tag inside with its padding. I want the width of the li depends on a''s padding but how ever I try, it doesn't work, if you know whats wrong, Please help me?

```
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">TAB 1</a><br />
       <ul class="sub-ul">
          <li>TEXT1</li>
          <li>TEXT1</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TAB 2</a><br />
      <ul class="sub-ul">
         <li>TEXT2</li>
         <li>TEXT2</li>
     </ul>
 </li>  
</ul>

//STYLE
ul >li {display: inline-block; margin-left: 0;} 
ul >li > a {padding: 10px 15px;}  I need li wrapping around this padding.
```

Comment: `a` elements are `inline` by default and therefore their padding doesn't really apply to things around them. Add `display:inline-block` - or even `display:block` and drop the `<br />` after it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Additionally, as you already have `display: inline-block` on the parent, you could use `display: inherit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
} 
li > a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
li ul li {
    display: block;
}
```